Why is my code failing for few test cases and passing for few test cases?
I am solving a problem where a date string is given in the form "Day Month Year" and then I have to return output in  string to the format YYYY-MM-DD. Below is my Problem Statement.

Given a date string in the form Day Month Year, where:

Day is in the set {"1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", ..., "30th", "31st"}.
Month is in the set {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"}.
Year is in the range [1900, 2100].

Convert the date string to the format YYYY-MM-DD, where:

YYYY denotes the 4 digit year.
MM denotes the 2 digit month.
DD denotes the 2 digit day.


I have written the code for it but it's only passing for few test cases and failing for few. like Below
class Solution(object):
    def reformatDate(self, date):
        list_date = date.split()
        YYYY = ""
        MM = ""
        DD = ""

        DD_dict = {
            "1st": "1", "2nd": "2", "3rd": "3", "4th": "4",
            "5th": "5", "6th": "6", "7th": "7", "8th": "8", "9th": "9", "10th": "10",
            "11th": "11", "12th": "12", "13th": "13", "14th": "14", "15th": "15", "16th": "16",
            "17th": "17", "18th": "18", "19th": "19", "20th": "20", "21st": "21", "22nd": "22",
            "23rd": "23", "24th": "24",
            "25th": "25", "26th": "26", "27th": "27", "28th": "28", "29th": "29", "30th": "30", "31st": "31"
        }

        MM_dict = {
            "Jan": "1", "Feb": "2", "Mar": "3", "Apr": "4",
            "May": "5", "Jun": "6", "Jul": "7", "Aug": "8", "Sep": "9", "Oct": "10",
            "Nov": "11", "Dec": "12"
        }

        for char in list_date:
            if char in DD_dict:
                if int(DD_dict[char]) < 10:
                    DD += '0' + DD_dict[char]
                else:
                    DD += DD_dict[char]
            elif char in MM_dict:
                if int(MM_dict[char]) < 10:
                    MM += '0' + MM_dict[char]
                else:
                    MM += MM_dict[char]
            else:
                YYYY += char

        return "".join(f'{int(YYYY)}-{int(MM)}-{int(DD)}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    date = "20th Oct 2052"
    d2 = "26th May 1960"

    print(Solution().reformatDate(date))
    print(Solution().reformatDate(d2))

So here, it's showing correct output for the input date = "20th Oct 2052" as 2052-10-20 but it's showing incorrect output for input d2 = "26th May 1960" as "1960-5-26". It should show output as "1960-05-26". Can you tell me where I am going wrong?

This question is similar to: How do I pad a string with zeros?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

just change 5 -> 05 and return "".join(f'{YYYY}-{MM}-{DD}')

Passing your tests
The problem lies in your return line :
return "".join(f'{int(YYYY)}-{int(MM)}-{int(DD)}')

Before this, you correctly put a '05' value in MM. (You can see it using a debugger, or adding a print(MM) before the return line).
But your MMstring variable is cast again in an integer. So now you have f"{int(MM)}"= '5'.
You don't need to do this integer casting.
A simple fix to your problem is to put your return line as such :
return "".join(f'{YYYY}-{MM}-{DD}')

Because your 3 variables YYYY, MM and DD are already strings.
Another solution to your problem
I see you are in Python 3.6+ because you are using f-strings.
This let's you use a convenient property of those f-strings.
MM = "5"
f"{int(MM):02d}" = "05"

In an f-string, if you use an integer variable, you can directly cast the string format you want it to be printed. See another linked question.
Therefore, you don't need all your work in the double for loop and the end of your class can just be :
# Assuming input string is always in the format "Day Month Year"
DD += DD_dict[list_date[0]]
MM += MM_dict[list_date[1]]
YYYY += list_date[2]

return "".join(f'{YYYY}-{int(MM):02d}-{int(DD):02d}')


Note that the join is totally useless. Furthermore, as has been said elsewhere, if you keep the OP's dictionaries, why not include the 0 padding in the values? The padding would only be necessary if you replace the 1st dictionary with string slicing.

formatted_date = f"{int(yyyy):04}-{int(mm):02}-{int(dd):02}"
print(formatted_date)  # Output: 2025-05-02
This is simple and the easiest way to return or print.

here's You are Corrected Code   


class Solution(object):
    def reformatDate(self, date):
        list_date = date.split()
        DD = ""
        MM = ""
        YYYY = ""

        DD_dict = {
            "1st": "01", "2nd": "02", "3rd": "03", "4th": "04",
            "5th": "05", "6th": "06", "7th": "07", "8th": "08", "9th": "09", "10th": "10",
            "11th": "11", "12th": "12", "13th": "13", "14th": "14", "15th": "15", "16th": "16",
            "17th": "17", "18th": "18", "19th": "19", "20th": "20", "21st": "21", "22nd": "22",
            "23rd": "23", "24th": "24",
            "25th": "25", "26th": "26", "27th": "27", "28th": "28", "29th": "29", "30th": "30", "31st": "31"
        }

        MM_dict = {
            "Jan": "01", "Feb": "02", "Mar": "03", "Apr": "04",
            "May": "05", "Jun": "06", "Jul": "07", "Aug": "08", "Sep": "09", "Oct": "10",
            "Nov": "11", "Dec": "12"
        }

        # Extracting day, month, and year from the split list
        DD = DD_dict[list_date[0]]  # First element is the day
        MM = MM_dict[list_date[1]]   # Second element is the month
        YYYY = list_date[2]           # Third element is the year

        # Return the formatted date
        return f"{YYYY}-{MM}-{DD}"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    date = "20th Oct 2052"
    d2 = "26th May 1960"

    print(Solution().reformatDate(date))  # Output: "2052-10-20"
    print(Solution().reformatDate(d2))    # Output: "1960-05-26"

